# How to send the form data to the JS program

Tags: javascript, html, json

user will give the url in the input type field in the Html page that url need to get in the JS program and then the JS program need to execute to fetch the data from webpage.

this is what  have done so far.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require("fs");
var url = ""

request(url, function(err, response, html){
  if(!err) {        
    var $ =cheerio.load(html); 
    var allItems = $('.clearfix').parent().children();
    var items = [];

    allItems.each(function(index) {

      var result = $('.clearfix').eq(index).parent().children().eq(1).find("a").text();

      if(result !== ""){  
           items.push(result);
      } 
    });

    fs.writeFile("output1.xls",JSON.stringify(items, null, 1),)
    console.log(items);
  }
});
```

Comment: What is the error please? could the last comma in this line be the problem: `fs.writeFile("output1.xls",JSON.stringify(items, null, 1),)` ?

Comment: this program is working fine but what i need is the user given url in the html page need to place in  var url = " "

Comment: have you tried var variable = document.getElementById( 'myDiv' ).innerHTML ?

Comment: this is my HTML part

<html>
    <body>
 
   <form id="url-form" method="POST" >

<input id="myURL" name="myURL" type="url"
       placeholder="http://www.example.com">

    </form>

</body>

Comment: how to combine both html and js  and need to execute

Comment: can anyone help

Comment: How to run the node js program automatically without using Terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the solution to your problem?

```
var url = document.getElementById('myURL').value
```